# Map two dataframes and perform sum operation using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-analysis

I have a dataframe **df**

```
df

   Object        Action  Cost1  Cost2
0     123      renovate  10000   2000
1     456  do something      0     10
2     789        review   1000     50
```

and a **dictionary** (called dictionary)

```
dictionary

{'Object_new': ['Object'],
 'Action_new': ['Action'],
 'Total_Cost': ['Cost1', 'Cost2']}
```

Further, I have a (at the beginning empty) dataframe **df_new** that should contain almost the identicall information as df, except that the column names need to be different (naming according to the dictionary) and that some columns from df should be consolidated (e.g. a sum-operation) based on the dictionary.

The result should look like this:

```
df_new

   Object_new    Action_new  Total_Cost
0         123      renovate       12000
1         456  do something          10
2         789        review        1050
```

How can I achieve this result using only the dictionary? I tried to use the .map() function but could not figure out how to perform the sum-operation with it.

The code to reproduce both dataframes and the dictionary are attached:

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd


### create df
data_df = {'Object':  [123, 456, 789],
        'Action': ['renovate', 'do something', 'review'],
        'Cost1': [10000, 0, 1000],
        'Cost2': [2000, 10, 50],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)


### create dictionary
dictionary = {'Object_new':['Object'], 
              'Action_new':['Action'], 
              'Total_Cost' : ['Cost1', 'Cost2']}


### create df_new
# data_df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Object_new', 'Action_new', 'Total_Cost' ])
data_df_new = {'Object_new':  [123, 456, 789],
        'Action_new': ['renovate', 'do something', 'review'],
        'Total_Cost': [12000, 10, 1050],
        }
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_df_new)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A play with `groupby`:

```
inv_dict = {x:k for k,v in dictionary.items() for x in v}
df_new =  df.groupby(df.columns.map(inv_dict),
                     axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
     Action_new  Object_new  Total_Cost
0      renovate         123       12000
1  do something         456          10
2        review         789        1050
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the complexity of your algorithm, I would suggest performing a `Series` addition operation to solve this problem.

Why? In `Pandas`, every column in a `DataFrame` works as a `Series` under the hood.

```
data_df_new = {
    'Object_new': df['Object'],
    'Action_new': df['Action'],
    'Total_Cost': (df['Cost1'] + df['Cost2'])  # Addition of two series
}

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_df_new)
```

Running this code will map every value contained in your dataset, which will be stored in our dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an empty data frame to copy the new column and use the `to_dict` to convert it to a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_df = {'Object':  [123, 456, 789],
        'Action': ['renovate', 'do something', 'review'],
        'Cost1': [10000, 0, 1000],
        'Cost2': [2000, 10, 50],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
print(df) 
MyEmptydf = pd.DataFrame()
MyEmptydf['Object_new']=df['Object']
MyEmptydf['Action_new']=df['Action']
MyEmptydf['Total_Cost'] = df['Cost1'] + df['Cost2']

print(MyEmptydf) 
dictionary = MyEmptydf.to_dict(orient="index")
print(dictionary)
```

you can run the code here:https://repl.it/repls/RealisticVillainousGlueware

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to entirely avoid pandas and only use the dictionary this should solve it

```
Object = []
totalcost = []
action = []
for i in range(0,3):
    Object.append(data_df['Object'][i])
    totalcost.append(data_df['Cost1'][i]+data_df['Cost2'][i])
    action.append(data_df['Action'][i])
dict2  = {'Object':Object, 'Action':action, 'TotalCost':totalcost}
```